# Why is wp_reset_postdata() restarting the loop from the first post?

Tags: wp-reset-postdata

I've used the second-last example showed here:
https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/each_connected

The only difference is that I've put **the_title** after echoing the connected posts. So my code is:

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'movie'
) );

p2p_type( 'movies_to_actors' )->each_connected( $my_query, array(), 'actors' );

p2p_type( 'movies_to_locations' )->each_connected( $my_query, array(), 'locations' );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php
    // Display connected actors
    echo '<p>Actors:</p>';

    foreach ( $post->actors as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        the_title();

        ...
    endforeach;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Display connected locations
    echo '<p>Filming locations:</p>';

    foreach ( $post->locations as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        the_title();

        ...
    endforeach;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The problem is that all the posts show me the title of the first post:

---

Actors: actors of post title n.1

Locations: locations of post title n.1

TITLE n.1

---

Actors: actors of post title n.2

Locations: locations of post title n.2

TITLE n.1 ***<<<--- WRONG!!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_reset_postdata/) restores the post from *main query*, which you do not seem to be using here at all. So before final `the_title()` call you jump out all the way to that post.

Your code seems to be tad problematic to me because both your outer and inner loops continuously rewrite `$post` global. If you move away from that in inner loops (by using versions of functions that take post/id to act on) you will likely escape multiple overrides/resets and issues like that.

Something like this:

```
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

    foreach ( $post->actors as $actor ) :

        echo get_the_title( $actor );

    endforeach;

endwhile;
```

Comment: Hi Rarst, thank you very much for the answer. Isn't the `while` at the 10th row the main query? Moreover, I've tried to use another variable in opposite to `$post` inside the two `foreach`, but it didn't affect `the_title()` inside them, so I've leave the `$post` variable. How can I rewrite the code in order to make it to work in your opinion?

Comment: @MarcoPanichi nope, what WP considers main query is held in global `$wp_query` variable and set up before you even reach template. What you have are two levels of secondary queries.

Comment: Ok! I understood. So I have to find a way to reset my post data to the first secondary level of that queries. You are talking about functions to move away from the inner loops: it could be a solution. What functions are you talking about?

Comment: @MarcoPanichi I have added code example to the answer

Comment: I was afraid that functions like `get_the_title()` (not used on the same post inside a loop) were performing some queries on the database (and it could be a problem because I have more than one entities connected and lots of posts). So I didn't tried. Instead I've checked [the code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L102) discovering that the function has nothing to do with database. I'll try instantly.

Comment: It works! Now I have to hope that I will find always a "get_" function for all of my needs...

Comment: @MarcoPanichi you'll get better with what to use when with experience :) If your question is answered with this please don't forget to accept the answer (green check mark) so it is marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to globalize `$post` in your code for `setup_postdata()` to do the right thing. It's a bit of a gotcha, as `setup_postdata()` merely sets up the related globals (`$id, $authordata, $currentday, $currentmonth, $page, $pages, $multipage, $more, $numpages`) but doesn't populate the global `$post` object, from which `the_title()` pulls the title.

Solution: `global $post;` before your loop.

In your case, `wp_reset_postdata()` isn't really necessary since you're never actually using the data from the main query, only the subqueries.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Bendoh. I've tried to add the globalization before the loop and then inside the two `foreach` but it doesn't work. Maybe because, as Rarst said, I'm using the $post variable inside the `foreach`